# Do I need to escape these in javascript?

Tags: javascript, escaping

My strings will hold the values:

```
"["
"[/blah]"
```

do I need to escape anything?

Is it just doubling the /?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to do anything / is not a special character

Answer (score 2):

If your string are `"[" "[/blah]"`, then you don't need to escape anything if you use single quote:

```
var foo = '"[" "[/blah]"';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a literal string square brackets or forward slash will not be interpreted so in your example you don't need to escape anything. Doubling applies to a backward slash only `\`